# How to merge a video,uiimage and a uiwebview in a video formate in objective c to share in social media website?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avassetwriter, avassetreader

I need to merge a video,`UIImage` and a `UIWebView` in a video format in Objective-C to share in social media website. I tried `AVAssetWriter` but could not implement it properly. I have shown video in my `UIView` with `MPMoviePlayerController` and added a `UIWebView` and a `UIImage` as subviews but Now I need to share it with Facebook. Can Anyone help me in this? Any Help and answer will be appreciated.

Comment: please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quicktime to record your device running your app. Save the output and upload that to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use some Video editing libraries to achieve that. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901112/video-editing-library-in-ios)

Also, there are some products that are meant for recording live gameplay on iOS, maybe you can make it work for you. Another link [here](https://developers.everyplay.com/)